# Notifications are sent to a single device

Tags: javascript, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo-notifications

I have a button that calls sendNotifications, and this obtains the FirebaseRealTime tokenIds that are ExpoToken but when sending the notifications it is only sent to the same device, if I have 10 tokens, 10 notifications are sent to a device. What is my mistake. I'm with Expo and React Native and expo-notifications

```
const RTDatabase = "https://e......firebaseio.com/";
 const sendNotifications = async () => {
   somePushTokens = [];
   fetch(`${RTDatabase}/users.json`)
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((data) => sendNotification(data))
     .catch((err) => console.log(err));
 };

 async function sendNotification(data) {
   Object.keys(data).forEach(async (item) => {
     const pushToken = data[item].token;
     console.log("pushToken", pushToken);
     await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync(
       {
         content: {
           title: "Alert",
           body: "Thanks",
         },
         trigger: { seconds: 1 },
       },
       { to: pushToken }
     );
   });
 }
```

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance, so I recommend you debug it locally to determine what is going on. Set a breakpoint on `const pushToken = data[item].token;`, run in the debugger until it stops there, and then check the value of every variable. Does everything look correct? If so, step to the next line and do the same thing. Continue until you find the first time a variable does not hold the value you expect it to.